# EF many-to-many relationship with specific scheam

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I wanna create an specific schema in DB for some Entities.
"Role" and "SystemKey" has many-to-many relation and both of theme is in "ACL" schema.

```
public class Role
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    //Navigation prop
    public virtual ICollection<SystemKey> SystemKeys { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class SystemKey
{
    public SystemKey()
    {
        Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    //Navigation prop
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

and in "OnModelCreating" i define :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Role", "ACL");
        modelBuilder.Entity<SystemKey>().ToTable("SystemKey", "ACL");
    }
}
```

buth, when DB generated, i saw role and system key generated in ACL schema and junction table(SystemKeyRole) created in dbo schema.
how can i forces that SystemKeyRole(junction table) generate in "ACL" schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by adding a configuration like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
    .HasMany(p => p.SystemKeys)
    .WithMany(p => p.Roles)
    .Map(p => p.ToTable("SystemKeyRole", "ACL"));
```